# How do I create a python installation as read only?

Tags: python

suppose I install python at the following path

```
/home/username/path/to/bin/python
```

How do I make this installation as "read-only" as if it was installed as root? Then any derived environment command will not alter this path. Furthermore it should not be possible to install any packages in "/home/username/path/to". The user will have access to pip and conda

Of course, I can tar and zip the original for safe keeping but I would prefer an alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this:

1. Navigate to your python installation directory

```bash
cd /home/username/some/path
```

2. Update the ownership of the directory to root

```bash
sudo chown -R root:root bin
```

3. Update the permissions of the directory to read-only

```bash
sudo chmod -R 555 bin
```

Comment: Some folders need read and some need execute permissions. This was going to be my solution but was worried if tampering with permissions could break packages

Comment: Most packages do not require write access to their own installation directories. If your concern is related upgrading your packages though, then I probably recommended a virtual env approach over a single installation if you are wanting to do a whole lot of that.